# How NQ Mobile Security app responds on uninstallation. I need to remove stored data from database on uninstallation.

Tags: android, database, uninstallation

I need to remove stored user info from database when user uninstall my app. But everywhere it is mentioned it is not possible. Then how NQ Mobile Security app reacts on Unstallation as shown in screenshot.[image]

Comment: They are exploiting a security flaw that I am trying to get fixed. "I need to remove stored user info from database when user uninstall my app" -- put the database in internal storage or app-specific locations on external storage (e.g.,`getExternalFilesDir()`), and the database will be removed automatically upon uninstallation.

Comment: Database is at server end, not in device.